# Backpack not generating "skin-purple" class on panel

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack, laravel-6

I started to follow the tutorial on https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.0/getting-started-basics on Laravel 6. But after running:

```php
# STEP 1. create migration
php artisan make:migration:schema create_tags_table --model=0 --schema="name:string:unique"
php artisan migrate

# STEP 2. create crud
php artisan backpack:crud tag #use singular, not plural
```

...the generated web page look messed up. I tracked the problem to the class "skin-purple" not being rendered on the body element.

The body tag on the /admin/dashboard page (which looks good) is:

```html
<body class="skin-purple sidebar-mini  pace-done" style="height: auto; min-height: 100%;">
```

The body tag on the /admin/tag page (the one I generated) is:

```html
<body class="app aside-menu-fixed sidebar-lg-show   pace-done pace-done" style="height: auto; min-height: 100%;">
```

If I add the skin purple class it fixes the problem.

I had some problems before with the backpack/generators version (I'm using ^2.0 now). Maybe it's related to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started a new project from scratch and just got everything working right on the first try, even the backpack/generators version was right. So I guess it was something that was fixed during last week.